# My navbar won't collapse after loading page on div through js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having troubles with my navbar because somehow when I get to see the collapse button and click one of the options that appear there when i try to collapse it, it gets stuck and won't get to normal unless I refresh the page.

This is the html that works with the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="nav">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Ans Dashboard</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbar-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="" data-target="customer_main"><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo " Customers";?></a></li>
                            <li class="" data-target="inventorypage"><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><?php echo " Inventory";?></a></li>
                            <li class="" data-target=""><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span><?php echo " Stats";?></a></li>
                            <li class="" data-target=""><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span><?php echo " Settings";?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="navbar-right text-center">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <form method="post" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><p class="navbar-text"><?php echo "Welcome"?><p></li>
                                    <li><button type="submit" name="logout" id="logout" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span><?php echo " Log out";?>
                                    <?php
                                        include("logout.php");
                                    ?>
                                    </button></li>
                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
    <!-- end of navbar-->
    <div id="content">
         <!-- Js page loads here -->
    </div>

    <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/mainpage.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript that loads the pages once the navbar area is clicked (mainpage.js)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var trigger = $('#navbar-1 ul li'), container = $('#content');

trigger.on('click', function(){

    var $this = $(this), target = $this.data('target');

    container.load(target + '.php');

    trigger.removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass("active");

    return false;

    });
});
```

EDIT: Already solved the problem, it had to with the pages being loaded had some problems with the way they were structured.

Comment: No need to call this click event manually bootstrap will handle itself.

Comment: The problem is that it worked normally before I added the click function but it didn't load the page right there without reloading. I'm trying to change the div after the navbar without changing url but after I added the js it does exactly that but now it won't collapse the navbar

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code, please check the my fiddle link appended below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trigger = $('#navbar-1 ul li'),
    container = $('#content');
  trigger.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      target = $this.data('target');
    container.load(target + '.php');
    trigger.removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhavanaditya/puej5yg3/)**

Thanks.

Comment: It looks the same to me. That is what it did before it loaded the pages in the div after the navbar through that js file.